# How to prevent trialing subscription from being created in Stripe before payment authentication succeeds?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm building an app which allowed users to register for a free trial (credit card is required). If the card requires authentication I run `stripe.confirmCardSetup()`. The problem is that the trialing subscription is created immediately when `stripe.confirmCardSetup()`. How can I wait with creating the subscription until the authentication is successful?

Comment: Hey nikt, The successful result of confirmCardSetup is the successful authentication. The order there makes sense. Alternatively, you could create a SetupIntent directly and use that to save card details to the customer before ever creating the Subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the answer cjav_dev, just to confirm you suggest to first create a SetupIntent and use that to complete authentication. If everything succeeds then I should create a subscription.

Comment: nikt, my first suggestion is that what you're doing is already correct and that calling confirmCardSetup is what handles successful authentication. If you wanted to completely separate card setup from creating the Subscription (which isn't required here) you could use the SetupIntent + Customer first then create the Subscription later.